# Pytorch running out of memory when initialising cnn model

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

Trying to implement a SAGEConv classifier using Pytorch. Here's the model definition:

```
embed_dim = 128
from torch_geometric.nn import GraphConv, TopKPooling, GatedGraphConv
from torch_geometric.nn import global_mean_pool as gap, global_max_pool as gmp
import torch.nn.functional as F
class Net(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()

    self.conv1 = SAGEConv(embed_dim, 128)
    self.pool1 = TopKPooling(128, ratio=0.8)
    self.conv2 = SAGEConv(128, 128)
    self.pool2 = TopKPooling(128, ratio=0.8)
    self.conv3 = SAGEConv(128, 128)
    self.pool3 = TopKPooling(128, ratio=0.8)
    self.item_embedding = torch.nn.Embedding(num_embeddings=df.item_id.max() +1, embedding_dim=embed_dim)
    self.lin1 = torch.nn.Linear(256, 128)
    self.lin2 = torch.nn.Linear(128, 64)
    self.lin3 = torch.nn.Linear(64, 1)
    self.bn1 = torch.nn.BatchNorm1d(128)
    self.bn2 = torch.nn.BatchNorm1d(64)
    self.act1 = torch.nn.ReLU()
    self.act2 = torch.nn.ReLU()        

def forward(self, data):
    x, edge_index, batch = data.x, data.edge_index, data.batch
    x = self.item_embedding(x)
    x = x.squeeze(1)        

    x = F.relu(self.conv1(x, edge_index))

    x, edge_index, _, batch, _ = self.pool1(x, edge_index, None, batch)
    x1 = torch.cat([gmp(x, batch), gap(x, batch)], dim=1)

    x = F.relu(self.conv2(x, edge_index))
 
    x, edge_index, _, batch, _ = self.pool2(x, edge_index, None, batch)
    x2 = torch.cat([gmp(x, batch), gap(x, batch)], dim=1)

    x = F.relu(self.conv3(x, edge_index))

    x, edge_index, _, batch, _ = self.pool3(x, edge_index, None, batch)
    x3 = torch.cat([gmp(x, batch), gap(x, batch)], dim=1)

    x = x1 + x2 + x3

    x = self.lin1(x)
    x = self.act1(x)
    x = self.lin2(x)
    x = self.act2(x)      
    x = F.dropout(x, p=0.5, training=self.training)

    x = torch.sigmoid(self.lin3(x)).squeeze(1)

    return x
```

I get the following error:

> RuntimeError: [enforce fail at ..\c10\core\CPUAllocator.cpp:75] data. DefaultCPUAllocator: not enough memory: you tried to allocate 603564952576 bytes. Buy new RAM!

When initialising the model:

```
device = torch.device('cuda')
model = Net().to(device)
```

I am new to pytorch. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try to reduce batch size ?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that df.item_id.max() was too large as I did not subset the data. Hence dimensionality was too high.